# Using Macros to Define Constants for CUDA

Tags: cuda, macros, constants, c-preprocessor

I'm trying to reduce the number of instructions and constant memory reads for a CUDA kernel.

As a result, I have realised that I can pull out the tile sizes from constant memory and turn them into macros. How do I define macros that evaluate to constants during preprocessing so that I can simply adjust three values and reduce the number of instructions performed in each kernel?

Here's an example:

```
#define TX 8
#define TY 6
#define TZ 4

#define TX2 (TX * 2)
#define TY2 (TY * 2)

#define OVER_TX (1.0f / float(TX))
```

Maybe this is already the case (or possibly handled by the nvcc compiler), but clearly I want the second block of macros to be evaluated by the preprocessor rather than replaced in the code so that it is not performed in every kernel. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you are going to use preprocessor defines to do this it's best practice to parenthesize everything, so instead of "#define TX2 TX * 2" do "#define TX2 (TX * 2)".  This is so you don't get unexpected behavior if the place you use the constant has operations that have equal or higher precedence than operations in the constant.  As defined currently "x / TX2" != "x / (TX2)" but this is _very_ difficult to find if it's causing a bug.

Comment: You're absolutely right, edited the answer. Also added a more complex example...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modern compilers will typically evaluate constants such as this at compile-time wherever possible, so you should be OK. This is also true for properly defined constants (i.e. using `const` rather than the "old skool" `#define` method).

Comment: Ok great, that's logical. What about more complex constructions such as #define (1.0f / float(TX)) This is even more critical not to be performed at runtime?

Comment: If TX is know at compile-time then yes, that should also get simplified. For performance-critical stuff like this though you ought to get into the habit of looking at the compiler output to see what is actually being generated - this can give useful insights into how to write your code to get the best out of the compiler and  also can give further ideas for micro-optimizations.